# Передать имя столбца в хранимую процедуру (mysql)

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица стран, возможно ли передать в хранимую процедуру имя столбца `name_* as name` чтоб избавиться от конкатекации `select id, name_{$language} as name from geo_country` ?

```
CREATE TABLE `geo_country` (
 `id` int NOT NULL,
 `iso` char(2) NOT NULL,
 `lat` decimal(9,6) DEFAULT NULL,
 `lon` decimal(9,6) DEFAULT NULL,
 `name_en` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `name_ru` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `name_de` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `name_fr` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `name_it` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `name_es` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `name_pt` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `name_ua` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: сделайте одно поле name типа json и храните в нем `{"en":"name", "ru":"имя", ...}` и добираться будет просто `name->>concat('$.', language)`. И главное, добавление нового языка превращается просто в запись новых данных не надо колонки в таблице новые создавать

Comment: *возможно ли передать в хранимую процедуру имя столбца* Да, возможно. Обычный строковый параметр. Процедуре пофиг, что в нём - это Ваша забота написать процедуру так. чтобы она использовала параметр как имя столбца (здравствуй, dynamic SQL).

Comment: @Mike вариант с JSON оказался самым удачным.